# Portable way to get all thread ids running inside a process.

Tags: linux, freebsd, c, pthreads

During the porting of an application form Linux to FreeBSD I came up with the following problem. I need to get all thread id of all threads running inside my application. In terms of PThreads, I need an instance of an `pthread_t` array which contain all threads in my program (either PThreads or OpenMP) to send a signal using `pthread_signal` to them. The current Linux implementation uses a non portable workaround by traversing the procfs to obtain all pids of a process:

```
int foreach_pid(void (*func)(pid_t, void *aux),void*aux){
 DIR *proc_dir;
 char dirname[256];
 pid_t pid;
 if ( ! func ) return -1;

 snprintf(dirname, sizeof(dirname), "/proc/%d/task", getpid());
 proc_dir = opendir(dirname);

 if (proc_dir) {
    /*  /proc available, iterate through tasks... */
    struct dirent *entry;
    while ((entry = readdir(proc_dir)) != NULL) {
        if(entry->d_name[0] == '.')
            continue;
        pid = atoi(entry->d_name);
        func(pid, aux);
    }
    closedir(proc_dir);
    return 0;
 } else {
    return -1;
 }
}
```

and uses the `kill` function to send the signals to all threads via their process ids. Obviously, this is not a portable to solution because even if `linprocfs` is mounted under FreeBSD it does not provide the *task* directory.

So what I am searching for is a routine/an interface/a library/a syscall to have a portable way to obtain similar information. Either as `pid_t` or preferable as `pthread_t`.

Comment: Can you register the `thread_id` somewhere via `pthread_self(3)` when a thread starts up?

Comment: The problem in most cases I am not able to modify the thread rotuines. For example in OpenMP.

Answer (score 1):

Obtaining the list of threads on FreeBSD is done with [`sysctl(3)`](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sysctl&sektion=3).
The OID is `CTL_KERN`, `KERN_PROC`, `KERN_PROC_ALL`.